# How to encrypt the password over jenkins script url using ansible playbook

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-cli

I am trying to encrypt the password over jenkins script url using below command, I am able to do it successfully.

Generating a CRUMB token is prerequisite for this, which i achieved it.

URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/script
```

script to encrypt:

```
println(hudson.util.Secret.fromString('password').getEncryptedValue())
```

Now, I am trying to achieve the same using **ansible playbook** uri module, i am not able to do it.
Can someone please help

```
curl -d "script=println(hudson.util.Secret.fromString('password').getEncryptedValue())" -v --user admin:<token-ID-for-user-admin> -H "$CRUMB" http://localhost:8080/scriptText
```

Note: I do not want to use **command** module in ansible to achieve this task

Please help.

Comment: If all you are trying to do is obscure that value in the output of the playbook, you could use ansible vault.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vault.html

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, though admittedly I disabled CSRF Protection so am not using a crumb

```
  tasks:
    - uri:
        url: "http://localhost:8080/scriptText"
        method: POST
        user: "{{ user }}"
        password: "{{ password }}"
        force_basic_auth: yes
        headers: "{{ crumb }}"
        body_format: form-urlencoded
        body: "script=println(hudson.util.Secret.fromString('{{ password_string }}').getEncryptedValue())"
        return_content: yes
      register: result

    - debug:
        var: result.content | trim
```

The `trim` filter is used to remove the trailing new line from the result

Comment: hey thats great, I tried as well and the code works for me, but as you mentioned catch here is need to disable the CSRF to simply pass the crumb value. But I tried using the crumb, faced a challenge where i got error: "**HTTP ERROR 403</h2>\n<p>Problem accessing /scriptText. Reason:\n<pre> No valid crumb was included in the request</p**" and it seems need to do lot of trimming work to extract the output from the registered ansible variable assigned to crumb variable. at this moment I am happy with the output